# umask value for group users to get read, write and execute permissions

Tags: permissions, umask

what value have I to specify for `umask` that the group users get read, write and execute?

Answer (score 0):

> what value have I to specify for umask that the group users get read,
>   write and execute?

That would be a `0` for the group. The `umask` value would then look something like:
`002`
Owner: `rwx`
Group: `rwx`
Others: `r-x`

**[Here is a good link on the matter.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)**